# Decode list to generic data with 4 selectors

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc-generics

I'm trying to generically derive instances for a decoder that uses lists. When I use `derive (Generic)` on a type with multiple selectors, the selectors are associated into a tree structure, which for example for four constructors looks like `((S1 a :*: S1 b) :*: (S1 c :*: S1 d))`. I can't figure out how to write the instances for this, even though I've figured out the algorithm how the selectors are associated.

Minimal example:

```hs
{-# language DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.List
import GHC.Generics
import Numeric.Natural

data Foo = Foo Int Int Int Int
    deriving (Generic, Show)

data Bar = Bar Int Int
    deriving (Generic, Show)

class Codec a where
    encode :: a -> [Int]
    default encode :: (Generic a, Codec' (Rep a)) => a -> [Int]
    encode = encode' . from
    decode :: [Int] -> a
    default decode :: (Generic a, Codec' (Rep a)) => [Int] -> a
    decode = to . decode'

class Codec' f where
    encode' :: f a -> [Int]
    decode' :: [Int] -> f a

instance Codec Int where
    encode = singleton
    decode = head

instance Codec c => Codec' (K1 i c) where
    encode' (K1 x) = encode x
    decode' x = K1 (decode x)

instance Codec' f => Codec' (M1 i t f) where
    encode' (M1 x) = encode' x
    decode' x = M1 (decode' x)

instance (Codec' f, Codec' g) => Codec' (f :*: g) where
    encode' (x :*: y) = encode' x <> encode' y
    decode' (x:xs) = decode' (singleton x) :*: decode' xs

instance Codec Foo
instance Codec Bar

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (decode $ encode (Bar 1 2) :: Bar)
    print (decode $ encode (Foo 1 2 3 4) :: Foo)
```

Output:

```
Bar 1 2
Foo 1 generic.hs: Prelude.head: empty list
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/List.hs:1644:3 in base:GHC.List
  errorEmptyList, called at libraries/base/GHC/List.hs:87:11 in base:GHC.List
  badHead, called at libraries/base/GHC/List.hs:83:28 in base:GHC.List
  head, called at /private/tmp/generic.hs:26:14 in main:Main
```

Expected output:

```
Bar 1 2
Foo 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I don't know what's the proper way to do it but ``decode' xs = decode' (take len xs) :*: decode' (drop len xs) where len = length xs `div` 2`` seems to work. It looks like the generic product is split at the middle (?) as in `(A :*: B) :*: (C :*: D)`. I'm not sure how that actually works; I don't know if this will also work on other types beyond the two examples you posted.

Comment: Perhaps, if you can change the `[Int]` encoding, you should consider adding the length of the first list as its first element when you concatenate them. E.g. instead of `encode' x <> encode' y` you could have something like `length en_x : en_x <> encode' y where en_x = encode' x` so that you know how to split the list in two at decoding time.

Comment: @chi Yes, splitting into two seems to work for all cases! I think that's how GHC's DeriveGeneric extension derives `Rep T` for selectors, too, at least in the paper I see a formula involving products and `floor(n / 2)` (https://dreixel.net/research/pdf/gdmh.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed in the comments will probably work, but if you'd like something less hacky, you want to reimplement your `decode`/`decode'` pair so that they operate more like parsers on an `[Int]` input stream, returning the "unused" portion of the stream when they've finished their work.  That is, your generic class ought to look something like:

```
class Codec' f where
    encode' :: f a -> [Int]
    decode' :: [Int] -> (f a, [Int])
```

and this lets you write:

```
instance (Codec' f, Codec' g) => Codec' (f :*: g) where
    encode' (x :*: y) = encode' x <> encode' y
    decode' xs = let (f, xs') = decode' xs
                     (g, xs'') = decode' xs'
                 in  (f :*: g, xs'')
```

where the first sub-`decode'` can determine how much of the input stream to absorb before invoking the second sub-`decode'` on the remainder.

The fully rewritten example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.List
import GHC.Generics
import Numeric.Natural
import Control.Arrow

data Foo = Foo Int Int Int Int
    deriving (Generic, Show)

data Bar = Bar Int Int
    deriving (Generic, Show)

class Codec a where
    encode :: a -> [Int]
    default encode :: (Generic a, Codec' (Rep a)) => a -> [Int]
    encode = encode' . from
    decode :: [Int] -> (a, [Int])
    default decode :: (Generic a, Codec' (Rep a)) => [Int] -> (a, [Int])
    decode = first to . decode'

class Codec' f where
    encode' :: f a -> [Int]
    decode' :: [Int] -> (f a, [Int])

instance Codec Int where
    encode = singleton
    decode (x:xs) = (x, xs)

instance Codec c => Codec' (K1 i c) where
    encode' (K1 x) = encode x
    decode' x = first K1 (decode x)

instance Codec' f => Codec' (M1 i t f) where
    encode' (M1 x) = encode' x
    decode' x = first M1 (decode' x)

instance (Codec' f, Codec' g) => Codec' (f :*: g) where
    encode' (x :*: y) = encode' x <> encode' y
    decode' xs = let (f, xs') = decode' xs
                     (g, xs'') = decode' xs'
                 in  (f :*: g, xs'')

instance Codec Foo
instance Codec Bar

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (decode $ encode (Bar 1 2) :: (Bar, [Int]))
    print (decode $ encode (Foo 1 2 3 4) :: (Foo, [Int]))
```